# Clickable area of an Expand/Collapse button

Tags: usability, user-expectation, experience

I have an Expand/Collapse button with text beside it and the button occupies an entire row/block on the page: **[+] Text Here**

What should the clickable area of this button be? Should it be just the icon [+], the icon and the text or the entire row?

Comment: I would say make  the whole `[+] Text Here` part clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[+]` icon is there to indicate that this `row` is expandable. So, in effect, you can make the whole row clickable.

To progressively indicate that a row is expandable you can at hover state

- Underline the row

`[+] My Documents` //**normal**

[[+] My Documents](http://www.google.com/)  //at **hover** state

- Show a number of child items like

`[+] My Documents` //**normal**

`[+] My Documents - 3 Folders and 10 files` //at **hover** state